# Homework error: Dereferencing pointer to incomplete type

Tags: c, struct

I am working on a homework assignment.

I'm running into the title error in this assignment. From what I've looked into so far, I know that there's a problem with the struct definition somewhere, but because that was done by my professor, I am inclined to think that it's something to do with the way I am calling the struct. 
Here is the relevant code.

in main.c (where I'm getting the errors from):

```
#include "processes.h"
//...
Processes * proc = proc_create(filename);  //line 90
                                           // the struct I'm trying to create
//...
for(i = 0; i < proc->size; i++) // line 100, where I get the first error of
                                // dereferencing pointer to an incomplete type
{
//Some code
}
```

in processes.c (where struct Processes is defined):

```
struct Processes{        
   struct Proc *array;      // array of Processes
   int internal_size;       // how big the array is total
   int size;                // how many valid Procs in the array
};
```

in processes.h:

```
typedef struct Processes Processes;
// Create your Processes struct using the filename of a schedule.txt
Processes * proc_create(char *filename);
```

If someone could please explain to me, exactly what this error means, and point me in the right direction to fixing it, that would be greatly appreciated! Also, If you need anything else, I'm happy to post other code. I was just pretty sure that this was the relevant code.

Comment: Move the definition of your `struct Processes` from your source file to your header.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the header file doesn't contain the complete definition of the `Processes` struct (only a forward declaration), the compiler cannot possibly know how to access its members. Consequently, `proc->size` isn't meaningful inside the main.c file. You will have to move the entire definition of the struct into the header file if you want to use its members directly. (Or, if creating an opaque type is your concern, then write an accessor function that simply returns `proc->size`.)

---

Also, your `proc_create()` function should probably take a `const char *` argument.

Comment: Do you know why C doesn't access from the .c file? or is there away to include the .c file instead of the .h file? Like, is there a way to make a Processes struct in another program without including the definition in the header file?

Comment: @DerekHalden No, there isn't. And it doesn't see the declaration because... well, that's a long story. The point is that the definition needs to be visible at compile time, for code generation (in order the compiler to be able to deduce and use memory offsets). Link time is too late.

Comment: Okay, so now I'm getting an error to an "undefined reference to 'proc_create'. Which is why I'm wondering if there is a different problem that I'm missing?

Comment: @DerekHalden No, that's another (second) problem. You have to link all object files together, in the correct order.

Comment: @DerekHalden "Do you know why C doesn't access from the .c file? or is there away to include the .c file instead of the .h file? " -- You shouldn't *want* to do that. Definitions of structures shared between files belong in header files in C; putting them in .c files is incorrect practice. As for why ... header files are textually included; there is no magic in C by which one C file can "access" definitions in another C file.

Comment: @DerekHalden ""undefined reference to 'proc_create'" -- proc_create isn't defined in the code you presented ... perhaps it isn't defined at all?